# Liquibase CSV import error

Tags: java, database, csv, import, liquibase

I wanted to import in Liquibase initial data, created CSV, added everything as documentation said, but it didnt work. The problem is, that Liquibase is adding misterious `[*]` for UUID values, and the query is failing

**flashcards.csv**

```
id,question,answer,deckId
6ab90e8c-3f28-46b2-81f3-b668f6908c09, testQuestion1, testAnswer1, c6c4d451-65dd-4ac0-9e53-974397c7bea7
a2670d1a-b8fe-4884-ba49-24f5d9458a12, testQuestion2, testAnswer2, c6c4d451-65dd-4ac0-9e53-974397c7bea7
3d55ce90-e2c6-4c0e-b94d-879f1194356c, testQuestion3, testAnswer3, c6c4d451-65dd-4ac0-9e53-974397c7bea7
3a581ad7-ac65-4a49-9697-9d111b3635a7, testQuestion4, testAnswer4, 3809da97-3fe2-4f13-bbc8-1442ea62d719
fc6583eb-99be-4f39-8de6-47fff909431e, testQuestion5, testAnswer5, 3809da97-3fe2-4f13-bbc8-1442ea62d719
```

**migrations.xml**

```
<loadData tableName="flashcards" file="initialData/flashcards.csv">
            <column name="id" type="COMPUTED" />
            <column name="question" type="STRING" />
            <column name="answer" type="STRING" />
            <column name="deckId" type="COMPUTED" />
</loadData>
```

id and deckId in database is set to UUID type, the table is successful.

Here's an error message :

> Syntax error in SQL statement "INSERT INTO PUBLIC.FLASHCARDS (ID,
>   QUESTION, ANSWER, DECKID) VALUES
>   (6AB90E8C[*]-3F28-46B2-81F3-B668F6908C09, ' testQuestion1', '
>   testAnswer1',  C6C4D451-65DD-4AC0-9E53-974397C7BEA7) ";
>
> expected "[, ::, *, /, %, +, -, ||, ~, !~, NOT, LIKE, REGEXP, IS, IN,
>   BETWEEN, AND, OR, ,, )";
>
> SQL statement: INSERT INTO PUBLIC.flashcards (id, question, answer,
>   deckId) VALUES (6ab90e8c-3f28-46b2-81f3-b668f6908c09, '
>   testQuestion1', ' testAnswer1',  c6c4d451-65dd-4ac0-9e53-974397c7bea7)
>   [42001-190] [Failed SQL:
>
> INSERT INTO PUBLIC.flashcards (id, question, answer, deckId) VALUES
>   (6ab90e8c-3f28-46b2-81f3-b668f6908c09, ' testQuestion1', '
>   testAnswer1',  c6c4d451-65dd-4ac0-9e53-974397c7bea7)]
>
> liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Syntax error in SQL statement
>   "INSERT INTO PUBLIC.FLASHCARDS (ID, QUESTION, ANSWER, DECKID) VALUES
>   (6AB90E8C[*]-3F28-46B2-81F3-B668F6908C09, ' testQuestion1', '
>   testAnswer1',  C6C4D451-65DD-4AC0-9E53-974397C7BEA7) ";
>
> expected "[, ::, *, /, %, +, -, ||, ~, !~, NOT, LIKE, REGEXP, IS, IN,
>   BETWEEN, AND, OR, ,, )";
>
> SQL statement: INSERT INTO PUBLIC.flashcards (id, question, answer,
>   deckId) VALUES (6ab90e8c-3f28-46b2-81f3-b668f6908c09, '
>   testQuestion1', ' testAnswer1',  c6c4d451-65dd-4ac0-9e53-974397c7bea7)
>   [42001-190]
>
> [Failed SQL: INSERT INTO PUBLIC.flashcards (id, question, answer,
>   deckId) VALUES (6ab90e8c-3f28-46b2-81f3-b668f6908c09, '
>   testQuestion1', ' testAnswer1', 
>   c6c4d451-65dd-4ac0-9e53-974397c7bea7)]

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is that in your migrations.xml, you are giving the type of the id and deckId columns as `computed` and they should be String.

Comment: `loadData type of uuid is not supported.  Please use BOOLEAN, NUMERIC, DATE, STRING, COMPUTED or SKIP` - This is an error which occurs when I try to make the field type UUID

Comment: Looks like that is going to be a problem then. Maybe if you use STRING?

Comment: If STRING does not work, this will probably be something that needs to be fixed in the liquibase CSV import code.

Comment: String worked :) Update Your answer so I can mark it as 'Accepted'